# Writing many void methods in a c++ class, and keeping track of variable changes

Tags: c++

I am a bit new to C++ having come from a very moderate C background so please excuse me if this question seems very elementary.

I have currently been given some C++ source code to read and modify.

However the code seems to me to be very ugly for a newbie but I am not sure whether the code is considered good C++ practice.

Basically there is only one class called STORAGE and all the information is public.

```
class STORAGE
{
public:
  STORAGE();
  virtual ~STORAGE();

  //DATA
  int np,nn;
  int istep;
  int print_step;
  //...and many more variables.


  //METHODS
  void eos(double rho, double e, double &p, double &cs);
  void ThermalEnergy(double rho,double &e,double p);
  void allocation();
  void initialization();
  void var_dt();
  // and many more methods which return void, 

};
```

Now when I am reading the algorithm which calls these methods, I see  each of them modifying many member variables of STORAGE, with many methods modifying the same set of variables, in a long list of method calls. Many of the methods are quite irritatingly of the type `void A ()`

With such a style , it seems to be very hard to keep  track mentally of the changes to the large number member-variables.

My question: Is this style of programming common to C++ when using classes? Giving a method access to all members of the class seems a bit dangerous, and it seems that a lot of buggy code could arise.

Psychologically for me it looks much more simpler to write code, if I know that the only variables being modified in a function call are the input variables to a function.

Comment: If a method is marked as `const` then it will throw a compiler error if it tries to modify any data member not marked as `mutable`. So, for example `void eos(double rho, double e, double &p, double &cs);` could be `void eos(double rho, double e, double &p, double &cs) const;` and then you can be fairly sure that it won't modify any member data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm..."Basically there is only one class called STORAGE and all the information is public." That certainly doesn't sound very encouraging.

Comment: "However the code seems to me to be very ugly" - your aesthetic sense is functioning perfectly normally, it is. It's perfectly normal for member functions to access member variables, however. Indeed, if they don't, there's no reason for them to be member functions in the first place, they should just be free functions.

Comment: Yes, this style is common. And yes, it is bad.

Answer (score 1):

"..all the information is public"
Yes, it it bad practice and contradicts the basic notion of encapsulation. Everybody outside the class, would be able see and modify all the members. Ideal is: to make the data members private, and provide public get/set methods (depending on need).

"Is this style of programming common to C++ when using classes?" -- Common but not good.

"Giving a method access to all members of the class seems a bit dangerous"
I think this is common, member functions should have access to member variables. Otherwise, who else will :) ? However, if you still want to prevent them to modify member variables, you can use the declare the function as const. (This approach is already described by Connor above).